# Creating Integers and adding them together to equal Hello world and 15

Tags: c++, integer, cout

completely new here to c++ and having some pretty dumb issues that I would not mind using a hand with.

so i need to create integers
these are my instructions

> inside the main function, write some code to do the following:
>
> 1. Create an integer called x.
> 2. Set it to 0.
> 3. Create another integer y.
> 4. Set it to 0.
> 5. Now set x equal to 5.
> 6. Now set y equal to 10.
> 7. Add x and y together and put the result in an integer called z.
> 8. Now add the following line of code after that:

this is what I have so far, but it will not succeed unless i change `void main()` to `int main()`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

I need to figure out how to place those integers, add them and have them succeed and debug.

Comment: `void main` is not a legal signature. That's why `void main` doesn't work, the compiler's just doing its job.

Comment: Rather than asking for ad hoc help you may be better searching for "C++ tutorial" on google.

Comment: Oh wow. This is pretty basic stuff you can easily pick up in the first chapters of a good introductory book.

Comment: What you have asked is pretty basic to any programming language. I recommend reading basic C++ programming online tutorials or a good C++ book.

Comment: I just started very recently i have tried for the last 45 mins before even asking I understand the concepts but its just much different from anything I have done before

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /* create an integer named x and set it to 0 */
    int x = 0;

    /* now set it to 5 */
    x = 5;

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```